# how to make date: @date.prev_month display as button instead of text

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I cannot for the life of me figure this out.  I have a calendar link that displays the previous (and next) month.

This was built right off of screencast #213 with Ryan Bates as a starting point.

I am trying to have the previous and next links display as buttons. Here is the code for the link to "previous" month ("next" month is the same)

```
<%= link_to "Previous", date: @date.prev_month  %>
```

now there is also a new event path which I did turn into a button, code below.

```
<%= link_to 'New Event', new_event_path, class: "btn btn-small btn-info"  %>
```

Adding the same button code does not work on the "previous" and "next" links.  I am relatively new to this stuff but it seems it has to do with the "date:" part and how the link is being created to previous and next month.

Can anyone make a suggestion how to get this to display as a button while still functioning the same, or how to achieve the same functionality while displaying as a button?

Comment: I think you need to add curly brackets. The link_to helper expects 2 hashes after the name. This should work: %= link_to "Previous", { date: @date.prev_month }, { class:  "btn btn-small btn-info"  %>

Comment: adding the brackets did the trick. Thanks!  I did not see any way to accept this as the answer, if you paste it into the answer section I will accept it.

Comment: Good to hear. Added my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add curly brackets, since the link_to helper expects 2 hashes after the name. This should work:

```
<%= link_to "Previous", { date: @date.prev_month }, { class: "btn btn-small btn-info" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a resource that should be able to help you with this issue: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to

I would play around with your next/previous links and check out the HTML that gets generated.  Also, you can right click the browser page and select "inspect element" in chrome.  That will help you debug the CSS.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for the link and comment.  After seeing the answer in the comments above I was able to find the explanation for why that worked when I followed the link.

Comment: Happy to help.  Good luck with your project!